# I have installed chef server, client version 12.0.1 and 12.0.3 respectively but unable to authenticate to chef server

Tags: chef-infra

When I run the following command
`knife client list` 
 I got the Below Error:
`The object you are looking for could not be found`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make sure your `chef_server_url` in `knife.rb` includes the `/organizations/<name>` bit. How did you create your knife config?