# Chef knife configuration

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I feel silly asking this question as it seems to work flawlessly for most people but I couldn't solve the following problem I encountered after setting up a Chef server 12 on RHEL 6 and the ChefDK 0.6.0 on my mac.

The chef server setup went through like charm as describeb on the documentation, no errors at all. When I wanted to use my machine as workstation to push cookbooks to the server I always get the error "The object you are looking for could not be found". According to other stackoverlfow posts ([0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27717465/i-have-installed-chef-server-client-version-12-0-1-and-12-0-3-respectively-but), [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21162458/enterprise-chef-workstation), [2](https://superuser.com/questions/834026/knife-commands-in-chef-is-not-working)) this is likely due to a configuration issue in knife.rb. Nevertheless, I used "knife configure" to setup the knife.rb file and double checked for any typos in the path. In addition, according to the knife.rb documentation page I used the attributes properly.

Anyone have an idea what could cause the problem?

```
log_level                :info
log_location             STDOUT
node_name                "nodermatt"
client_key               "/Users/odermatt/chef-repo/.chef/nodermatt.pem"
validation_client_name   "Adobe-validator.pem"
validation_key           "/Users/odermatt/chef-repo/.chef/Adobe-validator.pem"
chef_server_url          "https://sj1010005158157.corp.adobe.com:443/organizations/Adobe"
syntax_check_cache_path  "/Users/odermatt/chef-repo/.chef/syntax_check_cache"
cookbook_path [ "/Users/odermatt/chef-repo/cookbooks" ]
```

Comment: Does a `knife client list` return a list of clients?

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks for your comment. No, unfortunately knife client list prints the same output as the other commands, like the below:
$ knife client list
ERROR: The object you are looking for could not be found
Response: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-sransitional.dtd">

Comment: Can you then log into the chef server and access the "Generate Knife Config" menu item?

Comment: Is your organization spelled right? uppercase A? Can you check if your client exists using e.g. the web interface of the chef server?

Comment: Just to avoid any doubt, is the chef-server on it's own machine without any other web-server answering on the ssl port :443 ? (and I'm assuming the url is the host direct url and not a balancer url in front of it)

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32255783/chef-knife-commands-404-not-found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do perform knife commands under .chef directory. I too had same problem for change I tried under .chef directory, it was working. Try "knife client check" and "knife cookbook upload yourcookbook".

In knife.rb file, give chef_server_url as with your orgs name means which org you need to upload the cookbook. Typically be like "https://api.chef.io/organizations/orgname" and give path to your cookbooks directory.

Answer (score -1):

I had this same issue, could not run

> knife node run_list add nodename 'recipe[cron-delvalidate::default]' - cron-delvalidator recipe to the node named: chefnode

I found out, after reading this that it's `Chefnode`, not `chefnode`, capital "C". This solved my issue.

The response was:

```
Chefnode:
  run_list: recipe[cron-delvalidate::default]
```

Comment: That is a different problem